# Exclude file from Maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a normal maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>a.b.c.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <classifier>dist</classifier>
    <version>1.234</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

This is not a jar. It's just a set of .q files (q language).
I would like to exclude certain files.

I tried a few things and nothing seems to be working.

In the build, I added a maven-dependency-plugin, with unpack-dependencies as id, phase as package, goal to unpack, and inside the configuration, the artifact with the right groupId, artifactId, version, classifier, type, and the excludes.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
              <groupId>a.b.c.com</groupId>
              <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
              <version>1.1234</version>
              <type>zip</type>
              <classifier>dist</classifier>
              <excludes>code/lib/libcommon/filetoexclude.q</excludes>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems> 
        </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

And I can see in the logging that it's being logged as excluded but when I look at the actual target folder, it's still in there.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

As [per documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) `dependency:unpack-dependencies` simply "unpacks the project dependencies from the repository to a defined location", then it's up to you to do something with the unpacked resources.

I have a similar scenario in an application: a dependency contains a collection of .drl files (Drools language) and my application must use just a subset of those files.  Instead of phisically removing unwanted files, I keep the dependency unchanged (as it should be, IMHO) and I use a config param called "rulesPath" that lists the files used by the application.  Any other .drl file is simply ignored.  In other words I solve the problem at run-time (in my application), not build-time (in Maven).